# Magnolia CMS + Changing the AdminCentral UI Theme and images

Tags: magnolia

Is it possible to change AdminCentral UI Theme and Images in CE? as an example if client does not like the green colour background and making it customizable for company themes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to white brand UI for your company, you should get Enterprise version.